# How do I move my Wordpress domain to another domain?

Tags: migration, domain

So what I would like to do is, move the content of example.com/blog to yolo.com/blog. The yolo.com website is already live and has contents in it. So I just want to move my existing blog to a subdirectory on yolo.com. I have access to the Cpanels of both websites.

Comment: If you only need your blog post data, you have the option to backup your posts in wp admin. Goto tools->export. if you're moving your current site to subdirectory on new domain, you can create a new wp installation and import previously exported file **or** you can do a complete backup of your current site and then use it to recreate your website on new location. do only one from above two

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a database (with the corresponding username and permissions) in the cPanel of yolo.com, so your blog won't interfere with whatever you have in yolo.com. MySQL Assistant of cPanel is very easy and fast.
2. You need to download and install WordPress in yolo.com/blog folder. In your cpanel this usually is public_html/blog. [Install WordPress](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-manually).
3. Once the database is created and WordPress installed and running properly, you can start the migration. I recommend to use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/).

**Important**: there are many methods to achieve what you intend to do, I think the one described here is the most convenient.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. Your method looks convenient. I was actually about to try another method where I can take a backup of the blog via installtron and then go and restore it on yolo.com's installtron. Will that work?

Comment: I don't know installatron, but I guess it will work as long as you install the files on yourwebsite/blog and on a new database. Just be careful to not overwrite your yolo.com content/database.

Comment: Alright, so just to confirm, this is what I need to do: Take a backup using that plugin on my existing website, install wordpress on the new site, install the plugin on the new site and restore the backup. What I'm wondering is, will the the existing links be there on the new site too? Such as all the pages and categories?

Comment: If you use the plugin I recommend yes. It will import everything in your new installation and update the links.

Answer (score 0):

Is yolo.com a WordPress site ? If it's a Wordpress site, you can use [Wordpress importer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) to export content from example.com and import them to yolo.com .

example.com and yolo.com need to be online when you import your content

Dont' forget to add on .htacess file of example.com this instruction to keep your SEO and redirect users to yolo.com :

```
Redirect 301 /blog https://www.yolo.com/blog
```